# Server Error : TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

[image]

Here is the Code

```js
import { getProviders, signIn as SignIntoProvider } from "next-auth/react"

function signIn({ providers }) {
    return (
        <>
            {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <div key={provider.name}>
                    <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
                        Sign in with {provider.name}
                    </button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders();

    return {
        props: {
            providers
        }
    }
}

export default signIn
```

I am getting this error on pasting NextAuth.js sample code from the official website. I have the latest build of Node.js and Next.js.

You can find the whole source code here https://github.com/aadipoddar/instagram-react

Comment: Actually a small change, This is the link of the code and not the above one https://github.com/aadipoddar/instagram-react

Comment: You can use **nullish** and **falsy** operator, `||` is **falsy operator** and also `??` is **nullish operator**. `Object.values(providers ?? {})`

Comment: I am getting this error now https://photos.app.goo.gl/oa8kH455yAsdmCLx6

Comment: Neither of those repos seem to contain a component named `signIn`. Are you sure that's the right repository?

Comment: Now check https://github.com/aadipoddar/instagram-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000 not https://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

That's the result of the `map` function being called before `providers` actually has any value.
You can use conditional rendering to avoid such problems.

Try this:

```js
{providers && providers.length && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => ( ...
```

You can make it look nicer by storing it in a variable.

Like so:

```js
function signIn({ providers }) {
    const checkProviders = (
       providers &&
       providers.length
    );

    return (
        <>
            {checkProviders && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <div key={provider.name}>
                    <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
                        Sign in with {provider.name}
                    </button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried the following codes but I am now getting a different error, Here is the image of the error https://photos.app.goo.gl/oa8kH455yAsdmCLx6

Comment: This is unrelated to your original question. You're getting an error regarding the fetching from your API.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your NEXTAUTH_URL properly to your client url, for example

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't solve the ServerError.