# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object | NextAuth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to do a SignIn with Nextauth. This is my code:

```
import { getProviders, signIn as SignIntoProvider} from "next-auth/react";

function signIn({ providers }) {
    return (
        <>
        {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
            <div key={provider.name}>
              <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
                Sign in with {provider.name}
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const providers = await getProviders();

    return {
        props: {
            providers
        }
    }
}

export default signIn;
```

But I get this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzUKr.png)

I saw someone who had a similar/same error as me. I've tried all the suggested solutions. That is the question:

[Server Error : TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727734/server-error-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

When I try the solution with the green hook nothing happens. Not even an error.

The others also dont work.

What am I doing wrong??? Best wishes.

Comment: Can you console.log providers in getServerSideProps and post the output?

Comment: Is `signIn` a page component? `getServerSideProps` only works in page components.

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue, please have a look at the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463054/cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object-in-next-js/74508321#74508321). The main issue is to see if your `pageProps` gets passed down to your page components without any issue. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a null check like this:

```
function signIn({ providers }) {
  return (
    <>
      {providers && !!Object.keys(providers).length && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button onClick={() => SignIntoProvider(provider.id)}>
            Sign in with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: By doing this, nothing is happening! I am getting providers value as undefined. So its not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this helps:

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```